# How to parse a Dojo custom widget

Tags: dojo

I'm having some trouble with writing my own widget.  I've created a widget that inherits from _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin and _WidgetsInTemplateMixin (as I'm also trying to build a UI where the widgets will contain other widgets).  I'm loading the markup for the widget from a template using dojo/text.  Here is a snippet:

```
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dijit/_WidgetBase",
"dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
"dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
"dojo/text!./templates/LayerManagerWidget.html"
], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template) {
    return declare("myApp.ui.platforms.desktop.widgets.LayerManagerWidget", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {

        // summary:
        //     This widget provides the layer manager user interface component

        // templateString: string
        //     Inherited from _TemplatedMixin, used to specify an HTML file to provide the markup
        templateString: template

    });

});
```

It's working to some degree and I think the problem is with parsing.  Because the widgets aren't all required right from the start, I don't think they are being parsed.  Some of the examples on the dojo widget tutorials include dojo/ready and dojo/parser in the widget and parse it but I haven't been able to work out how to do this: those same examples don't have a 'return' before the declare statement which I don't quite understand as then how do you then later instantiate the widget with something like var myWidget = new MyWidget(); ?

So I guess the main part of the question is, in the above example, where do I put a parser.parse() call (or in general, how do I make sure this widget gets parsed)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried passing the root widget node to `parser.parse(...)` after you have made a new widget?

Comment: @Shoe Hi, thanks for the comment. No, I haven't tried that - can you elaborate where/when that would go?  i.e. somewhere in the widget, or in the class that instantiates it, in which case before / after startup()? Thanks again!

Comment: In your widget you might override the `startup` method and pass in the widget root node to parser.parse(node).

Comment: @Shoe thanks again, still a bit confused though but noticed another symptom.  The html I'm loading for the widget is very simple, just <div><div id="toolsTitle">Tools</div></div>.  In the postCreate I'm trying to do dom.byId("toolsTitle") but it comes back with undefined.  I've just tried it in the startup(), both with and without a call to parser.parse but still get undefined.  Does this help pinpoint what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `data-dojo-attach-point='toolsTitle'` and in your widget `this.toolsTitle`

Comment: @Shoe duh!  I had created a simplified widget to try and take out anything causing me a problem and completely forgot about this.  Thanks, it's coming together now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the widget code itself you shouldn't put stuff like `parser.parse()` or anything similar. To make sure a widget is being parsed, you have to import it in your main JavaScript file (one with a `require()` block) and parse it either automatically or manually.

So for example, if the widget is located in a file called **MyWidget.js**, you put something like this in your main JavaScript file (for example **app.js**):

```js
require([ "custom/MyWidget", "dojo/parser" ]);
```

This will work just fine if you have configured Dojo to parse automatically. If you rather want to parse manually, you could use:

```js
require([ "dojo/parser", "custom/MyWidget", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(parser) {
    parser.parse(); // Parses the entire DOM
});
```

If you want to programmatically create an instance of your widget, you don't need to parse at all, you just use:

```js
require([ "custom/MyWidget", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(MyWidget) {
    var myWidget = new MyWidget({ }, "myDomNodeId");
});
```

For example: http://plnkr.co/edit/K3Zln6Q00g6v2DQeWcIM?p=preview

Comment: thanks. I should have mentioned that I'm not 'require'ing all of the widgets on the html page as my plan is to load certain ones only if required. Therefore in one of the modules I've got some logic that determines what is required and then has another require statement to require them and then programmatically create the various widgets.  So I don't need to parse a programmatically created widget, so I think that's the way to go. For widgets declared declaratively in a parent widgets html template and parent widget created programmatically does child need parsing and how?  Thanks!

Comment: The moment your widget is instantiated (and you're using `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`), then they're automatically parsed as well. However, you have to add the widget dependencies to the list of modules you import in your widget (so add them to the `define()`).

Comment: I also made an example using a custom widget with widgets inside it that is being loaded programmatically: http://plnkr.co/edit/K3Zln6Q00g6v2DQeWcIM?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Did you read

> http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/writingWidgets.html

->

```
ready(function(){
    // Call the parser manually so it runs after our widget is defined, and page has finished loading
    parser.parse();
});
```

Since you write a custom dijit widget, you can read about other functions in its lifecycle here:

> http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/understanding_widgetbase/

-> "postCreate", "startup"

Comment: parser.parse() alone will parse the entire dom. If you have already parsed the dom it will break.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but yes: read and read the tutorials but still struggling!  Where in my above example would you put the ready statement though?  It can't go after the declare because of the return.